# Importing fbx models made in Cinema4D in unity at runtime

Tags: unity, fbx

In my app I have requirement that I will be given a url and using this url I have to download a fbx model and then show it in the scene.

I am able to download the model from the url using the below code.

```
IEnumerator loadModel(string modelName)
{
    if (!isDownloaded)
    {

        string targetUrl = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000/" + modelName;
        Debug.Log("targetUrl" + targetUrl);
        WWW www = new WWW(targetUrl);


        yield return www;
        if (www.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log("downloaded " + www.bytesDownloaded);
            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath+"/Resources", modelName);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, www.bytes);
            isDownloaded = true;

            LoadAndAttachModel(imageTargetTransform, modelName);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.bytesDownloaded);
        }
    }
}
```

And with the below code I tried using loading the model in the scene

```
public void LoadAndAttachModel(Transform parent, String modelName)
{
    Debug.Log(modelName);
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/Resources", modelName);
    String name = modelName.Substring(0, modelName.IndexOf("."));
    GameObject load = Resources.Load(modelName) as GameObject;
    Debug.Log(load.name);
    if (load != null)
        {
           // load.transform.parent = parent;
            load.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            load.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(90, 90, 0));
            load.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        }

    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Can't find boneName : " + parent);
    }
}
```

but this code always gives exception that the gameobject load is null. I tried with the obj model and that was working fine but with fbx models this is giving exception every time.

So how can I instantiate the downloaded gameobject in my scene ?

Comment: I know this probably doesn't help your problem, but this sounds terribly insecure.

Comment: insecure in what means?

Comment: You're downloading something off a website. It introduces a dozen of security hole candidates. The website could be seized, the traffic could get changed by an MITM, etc.

Comment: that is not a website, that is my app backend and I am downloading it from backend server not any third party sites.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't download models on the fly like this and put them in your game. However, it would be possible with [asset bundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) .

Comment: @Hellium well I am able to download them easily but I am not able to load them in my scene. For asset bundles they need to be first made in unity editor but that is not the case here. I already have a working project using asset bundle but that's not according to the requirement

Comment: @VivekMishra Unity doesn't have runtime model import support. You're not able to load the models because they're not assets, they need to be imported into the game first or made into an asset bundle. Alternatively you could use some [free or paid alternatives from the assetstore](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=runtime&model&import) for that.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I searched for assets too but they are not working with every fbx model and have their limitations too. As far as assetbundles are concerned they required to be build as assetbundles beforehand, while in my case models will be uploaded using backend panel and it's url will be provided to me

Comment: @VivekMishra Then you need certain limitations on the models (like measurements, orientation and maximum vertices). I've worked on something similar before and if the models are wildly different from each other, there's not much to be done (other than prepare them by hand, into assetbundles).

Comment: I actually found an asset that helps to load obj models like the above. So I think I have to limit model upload to obj only.